# Problems accessing codecs with ggplot and gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, ffmpeg, gganimate

Using gganimate. Can't figure out how to properly access functionality of ffmpeg, specifically I want to change the codec I'm using in the video file I'm outputting.

```
# load packages
library(ggplot)
library(animation)
library(gganimate)

# Here's my data.frame
myDf <- data.frame(
    year = c(1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), 
    bottom50 = c(0.195, 0.191, 0.187, 0.192, 0.196, 0.205, 0.207, 0.210, 0.209, 0.204, 0.203, 0.204, 0.205, 0.203, 0.202, 0.200, 0.200, 0.201, 0.199, 0.195, 0.190, 0.183, 0.179, 0.179, 0.177, 0.172, 0.169, 0.169, 0.168, 0.166, 0.158, 0.159, 0.158, 0.154, 0.151, 0.148, 0.149, 0.148, 0.146, 0.149, 0.148, 0.145, 0.142, 0.138, 0.135, 0.137, 0.137, 0.136, 0.130, 0.127, 0.123, 0.127, 0.125), top1 = c(0.126, 0.127, 0.129, 0.128, 0.126, 0.123, 0.122, 0.115, 0.110, 0.111, 0.111, 0.109, 0.106, 0.105, 0.105, 0.107, 0.108, 0.111, 0.107, 0.110, 0.112, 0.115, 0.125, 0.125, 0.122, 0.133, 0.149, 0.145, 0.145, 0.139, 0.150, 0.146, 0.147, 0.153, 0.160, 0.166, 0.169, 0.177, 0.183, 0.173, 0.171, 0.172, 0.183, 0.194, 0.201, 0.199, 0.195, 0.185, 0.198, 0.196, 0.208, 0.196, 0.202)
)

#Basic plot
p <- ggplot(myDf, aes(x = year, y = bottom50, frame = year)) + 
    geom_line(color = "dodgerblue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = top1), color = "darkred")
```

The non-animated version gets me what I want:

[image]

And I get an animation version output to video with:

```
gganimate(p, interval = .1, title_frame = FALSE, "income.mp4")
```

That's fine, but I want to change some the output parameters, specifically: alter the dimensions, the frame rate, and use a different codec.

```
# change some of the options
ani.options(ani.height = 1080, ani.width = 1920, 
            interval = 0.04166667, other.opts = "-vcodec qtrle -f mov")
# re-animate
gganimate(p, title_frame = FALSE, "income.mov")
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Error in animation_saver(saver, filename) : 
  Don't know how to save animation of type mov
```

I'm using '.mov' as my file extension because I'm trying to change to the Animation codec (so it's no longer a .mp4 wrapper). I've got ffmpeg installed, so this is probably a syntax issue. But the documentation isn't very clear here; gganimate doesn't have any documentation on changing codecs (or outputting any video besides an mp4), and the animation package is light on specifics as well.

Comment: `system('ffmpeg -formats')` should show you whether the codec is available, which it almost certainly is. The limitation is `gganimate:::animation_saver`, which if you look at its code, doesn't have an option for .mov. You could certainly do it through `animation::saveVideo`, though you'll need to collate the plots manually or dig into `gganimate`'s internals to get it to do so for you.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for cleaning up the code to make it easier to read. Going under the hood of gganimate might be a bit beyond my coding skills but maybe not by much. Let me look around and see what I can learn toward that end. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it entirely in `animation` (or even `ffmpeg`) if you prefer if you just create all the plots directly instead of via an aesthetic. Make a directory, then use `lapply` (or variants) and `ggsave`, and you should have what you need.